# Inequality involving sums of reciprocals and n-th root

Tags: inequality, radicals, harmonic-numbers

I'm trying to prove this inequality. Let n be a positive integer. Prove that:
$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n-1}\ge n\sqrt[n]{2}-n$$
I've tried doing it with algebraic, geometric, and harmonic mean, the integral bound (and realised both sides are decreasing and going towards $\log 2$), but none have worked. I'd be grateful if anyone could show me the trick needed.

Comment: Have you tried using induction?

Comment: @Hawk: have you tried using induction for this problem? Unless I am missing something obvious, this is a red herring.

Comment: @robjohn Obviously you are not missing anything...and I did not mean to use induction directly to the problem but after some manipulations because if we use induction here, then we would have to prove yet another inequality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write this as
$$2^{1/n} \le \frac{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) + \dots + \left(1 + \frac{1}{2n-1}\right)}{n}.$$
The result follows from AM-GM once you show that (for example by induction)
$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\right) \dots \left(1 + \frac{1}{2n-1} \right) = 2.$$

Comment: How did you ever come up with doing AM-GM on the numbers $1+\frac1k$? I know, once you say their product is $2$ it becomes obvious, but you should already know this trick to be able to invent this, no?

Comment: @barto: Well, the power $1/n$ hints at AM-GM. To use AM-GM you want some approximately same size numbers. From this point of view distributing the $n$ evenly among the $n$ terms makes sense.

Comment: Hmm, yes. Thanks for explaining your reasoning behind it.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I would never have guessed that you need to split the n into n 1s. Great idea!

Answer (score 3):

Since $\log(1+x)$ is concave, Jensen's inequality says that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n\log(2)
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\log\left(1+\frac1k\right)\\
&\le\log\left(1+\frac1n\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\frac1k\right)\\
\end{align}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
2^{1/n}\le1+\frac1n\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\frac1k
$$
and therefore,
$$
n2^{1/n}-n\le\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\frac1k
$$